# How can i make the browsed file the target for process, instead of it being hard coded in?

Tags: python, tkinter

Instead of "mbox = ?????????" in the def start_processing(self) section, how do i make it the file that has been uploaded. This was originaly hard coded however have changed it to a file upload? Thanks

```
class App:

def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master

    # call start to initialize to create the UI elemets
    self.start()

def start(self):
    self.master.title("Extract Email Headers")

    self.now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # CREATE A TEXT/LABEL
    # create a variable with text
    label01 = "Please select the .mbox file you would like to analyse"
    # put "label01" in "self.master" which is the window/frame
    # then, put in the first row (row=0) and in the 2nd column     (column=1),
    # align it to "West"/"W"
    tkinter.Label(
        self.master, text=label01).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.W)

    # CREATE A TEXTBOX
    self.filelocation = tkinter.Entry(self.master)
    self.filelocation["width"] = 60
    self.filelocation.focus_set()
    self.filelocation.grid(row=1, column=0)

    # CREATE A BUTTON WITH "ASK TO OPEN A FILE"
    # see: def browse_file(self)
    self.open_file = tkinter.Button(
        self.master, text="Browse...", command=self.browse_file)
    # put it beside the filelocation textbox
    self.open_file.grid(row=1, column=1)



    # now for a button
    self.submit = tkinter.Button(
        self.master, text="Execute!", command=self.start_processing,
        fg="red")
    self.submit.grid(row=3, column=0)

def start_processing(self):
    date1= "Tue, 18 Jan 2015 15:00:37"
    date2="Wed, 23 Jan 2015 15:00:37"
    date1 = parser.parse(date1)
    date2 = parser.parse(date2)
    f = open("results.txt","w")
    mbox = ????????????????????
    count = 0

    for msg in mbox:
        pprint.pprint(msg._headers, stream = f)
        tempdate = parser.parse(msg['Date'])
        print(tempdate)


    f.close()
    print(count)
    pass

def browse_file(self):
    # put the result in self.filename
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open a file...")

    # this will set the text of the self.filelocation
    self.filelocation.insert(0, self.filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to store the file path in a `StringVar`. TK uses special *control variables* to provide functionality for Entry objects. You can create a string control variable by calling the function `tk.StringVar()`.

You want to create the variable when you initialize your UI, so in your `start()` method:

```
    # CREATE A TEXTBOX
    self.filepath = tkinter.StringVar() # This will hold the value of self.filelocation
        # We set it to the "textvariable" option of the new entry
    self.filelocation = tkinter.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.filepath)
    self.filelocation["width"] = 60
    self.filelocation.focus_set()
    self.filelocation.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Now when we want to retrieve the value of it we use the `get()` method. In your `start_processing()` method:

```
    # Here it opens the file, but you may want to do something else
    mbox = open(self.filepath.get(),'r')
```

The way you set the value in your `browse_file()` method can be updated to use the control variable quite easily. Instead of inserting into the entry box directly, we'll set the value of our control variable and it will automatically update in the text entry field. In `browse_file()`:

```
   # this will set the text of the self.filelocation
   self.filepath.set( self.filename )
```

Now you can properly set and retrieve the value of `self.filelocation` the intended way. You can change the name of `self.filepath` to whatever you want, of course.

For more information:

- [Tkinter 8.5 Reference - Control Variables](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html)
- [TkDocs - Tk Tutorial - Basic Widgets - Entry](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#entry)

Comment: Im not going to lie mate, you have fully lost me there :)

Comment: @Stemain2 Read through this and see if you understand how they set up the entry field: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html

Comment: Or tell me where I lost you so that I know what to explain

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need an instance of `StringVar` to make this work. That's one way to do it, but the entry widget has a method for setting and getting data.

Comment: @BryanOakley while there are methods for retrieving data directly from an entry widget, I believe they're less easily maintained. If the data is stored in a StringVar, you can easily manipulate it without having to clunkily retrieve and insert text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain if `mbox` is supposed to be an open file, a list, a tuple, or some custom object. I'm going to assume it's an open file, since you have a function to pick a filename.

If that's the case, all you need to do is call the `get` method of the entry widget to get whatever the user typed:

```
mbox_name = self.filelocation.get()
mbox = open(mbox_name, "r")
for msg in mbox:
    ...
```